# Is std::string::push_back faster than std::string::append?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, push-back

I usually use the `+=` operator to add content to an `std::string` which is seemingly the same as `std::string::append`. There is also the `push_back` method for a string which allows to add one character at a time. For now, I always use `+=` since it is readable compared to other methods, even if I only want to add one character.

Should I prefer `push_back` when I need to append one character only? Are there any performance issues significant enough to use `push_back` when adding one character?

Comment: My answer is no and no. I generally use `+=` too.

Comment: If you have C++20, I'd say use std::format. Or else I would use std::ostringstream for building up strings. There are so many ways, if it is performance you worry about, measure before you choose what's best. If not pick what's most readable.

Comment: imho `std::string` is one of the most quirky types. I suppose it only has `push_back` because it can and for similarity with other containers

Comment: Most likely one will be implemented in the terms of the other anyway, resulting in the former being inlined, so no performance difference. You *do* get one, though, if using `+=` inapropriately, using string literals for a single character, i.e. `std::string() += "s"` (correct would be `std::string() += 's'`), though the difference should be marginal and only notable in high performance code.

Comment: I expect it's main purpose is to have a consistent interface between containers in the standard library.

Comment: If you decide to replace `std::string` with say `std::vector` you will have to change less code than if you use `+=`.

Comment: What can be a much larger performance issue is, in contrast, not `reserve`ing sufficient memory in advance!

Comment: imho your change in title made the question worse. If you want to know which is faster you dont need to ask you can and should  measure

Comment: ***Should I prefer push_back when I need to append one character only?*** Is opinion based. Being faster or not is something you will have to measure for your `c++` implementation. I expect that if there is a difference in performance it will be so small that it will not be easily measurable unless you are doing 10s of thousands of inserts.

Comment: std::string is one of the containers. Containers are required to support the specific interface for the algorithm library. Hence std::string::push_back exists but does not exclude other convenient API. Using one or another is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is limited by this

> when I need to append one character only?

I think it's fair we keep `basic_string& operator+=(const _CharT*)` out of the question and concentrate on `basic_string& operator+=(_CharT)` vs `void push_back(_CharT)`.

In this case, as far as GCC is concerned, `+=` simply calls `push_back` and returns `*this` by reference,

```cpp
_GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
basic_string&
operator+=(_CharT __c)
{
    this->push_back(__c);
    return *this;
}
```

so the performance should be the same.

Most likely, other implementation of the STL will use a similar approach.

Comment: MSVC does the same: `_CONSTEXPR20 basic_string& operator+=(_Elem _Ch) {
        push_back(_Ch);
        return *this;
    }`